# Creating csv file from pandas dataframe as per the sheet names in file from condition over a column

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a excel file which has multiple sheets(6) in it. I am writing a python script to convert the each individual sheet into a csv file.

My input file looks like this and this is for example sheetname = class5

```
Name   ID  Result

Mark   11   Pass
Tom    22   Fail
Jane   33   Pass
Colin  44   Not Appeared
```

like this I have multiple sheets in the excel

I need to convert them in csv file having just 'Name' and sheetname for only 'pass' and 'fail' candidates and not for 'not appeared'candidates like this:

```
csv file to be created class5.csv which has content just:

Mark,class5
Tom,class5
Jane,class5

Note: No 'colin' as he did not appear
```

This one one sheet like this I have multiple sheets so I wrote the script which reads the excel and creates the Name,class csv file but I am not able to put filter from the column 'Result' for not displaying 'Not appeared' as now for this code I have all the Pass, fail and not appeared

```
xls = pd.read_excel('path_of_file',sheet_name = None)
for sheet_name, df in xls.items():
    df['sheet'] = sheet_name
    df[['Name','sheet']].to_csv(f'{sheet_name}.csv', header=False)
```

Need to know how I can add filter to my Result column to remove just 'Not appeared' students name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by condition and also by column name `Name` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
xls = pd.read_excel('path_of_file',sheet_name = None)
for sheet_name, df in xls.items():
    df = df.loc[df["Result"] != 'Not Appeared', ['Name']].copy()
    df['sheet'] = sheet_name
    df.to_csv(f'{sheet_name}.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: I am getting error in both for the first one(Dataframe.query) the error is:    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST) ```Result !='Not appeared' SyntaxError: invalid syntax  however all syntax is correct``` however syntax is correct

Comment: @SachinKumar - Sometimes happen, if copied `''`. Btw, I find problem is second solution, I forget for `loc` -  is necessary change `df = df[df["Result"] != 'Not Appeared', ['Name']].copy()` to `df = df.loc[df["Result"] != 'Not Appeared', ['Name']].copy()`

Comment: For the second from boolean index I am getting this error: ```File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
Name: Final Review, Length: 241, dtype: bool, ['Name'])' is an invalid key```

Comment: @SachinKumar - there are for each shetname all 3 columns? `Name,   ID,  Result`?

Comment: Yes same number of columns in each sheet

Comment: Second I am able to execute using loc